# Security risk of copying

Tags: disk-encryption, backup

I need to back up an encrypted drive, if the data gets corrupted I'd have another copy

I don't have another drive that I trust not to have been compromised right now.

My idea is to copy an encrypted image of the drive to the possibly compromised drive, and when I need it, I copy the image back to a secure drive. The data never gets decrypted on the possibly compromised drive, would I be vulnerable to any attacks?

Comment: Possibly compromised in what way? If compromised is it attached to the internet in any way? Copying an encrypted image to a compromised drive might be handing an attacker a copy of the image, but as long as the key was not on that drive in plaintext then you aren't handing them the information you need to use that image. Your image should be as secure as the method you used to encrypt it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this leaves you vulnerable to attacks involving diffing the ciphertexts on the two drives. Instead, you should create a new encrypted container on the backup drive, and then copy only the inner image from the primary to the backup.

Comment: If the drive is copied, it's identical, there's nothing to dif. Even if there was, AES would fall like dominoes if this was realistic, it's not. Your references to **container** and **inner** imply you're thinking of encrypted containers like Veracrypt as opposed to the stated drive.

Comment: @user10216038 it's identical at first, but not after you keep using the original for a while.  And it's not clear to me whether the OP is using something like Veracrypt or not, so I made the better-safe-than-sorry assumption that they are.

Answer (score -3):

“*I need to back up an encrypted drive, if the data gets corrupted I'd have another copy*”

Yes this is very straight forward, I do it regularly via a “dd” of the drive. Note that this needs to be done from an **UNMOUNTED** source drive!

"*My idea is to copy an encrypted image of the drive to the possibly compromised drive...*"

It's not clear exactly what you mean by ***the possibly compromised drive***.

If you intend overwriting the drive as the destination from the copy, then the content of the destination drive is irrelevant as you will be destroying that content in the output process.

If you intend writing your encrypted image (which won't compress by the way) as a file on your **questionable** **drive**, then things get more complex. In order to write a file, your questionable drive will need to be mounted. Malware on your questionable drive is just a file that does nothing if you don't run it. As long as your mount process doesn't auto run stuff, you can safely write and restore to and from that questionable drive just fine. Just keep in mind that mistakes happen, you may want to overwrite your questionable drive to remove its question.